# Flask: app.register_blueprint works fine when run using the builtin app.run. However fails when tied to apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, uwsgi

Flask: app.register_blueprint works fine when run using the builtin app.run. However fails when tied to apache. I am getting a 404 error when I access the url

http://ipadddress/register - 404 Not Found

I have setup a Flask App with Apache2 and wsgi configuration. Below is the code. I have done the apache setup using [Digital Ocean - Apache Flask configuration on debian systems](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

## **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from register.registeration import account_api

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(account_api)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

## register/registration.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template


account_api = Blueprint('account_api', __name__)

@account_api.route('/register')
def register():
    return render_template('register.html')
```

## flaskapp.wsgi

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/pi/ReSTServices/env/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'MyHappyNewsWithHacker'
```

## Project Structure

```
├── flaskapp.wsgi
├── __init__.py
├── register
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── registeration.py
├── static
│   └── dist
│       ├── css
│       │   ├── bootstrap.css
│       │   ├── bootstrap.css.map
│       │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│       │   ├── bootstrap.min.css.map
│       │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
│       │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css.map
│       │   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
│       │   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css.map
│       │   ├── font-awesome.min.css
│       │   ├── sticky_footer.css
│       │   └── style.css
│       ├── fonts
│       │   ├── FontAwesome.otf
│       │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.eot
│       │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.svg
│       │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.ttf
│       │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.woff
│       │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.woff2
│       │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
│       │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
│       │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
│       │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
│       │   └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
│       ├── img
│       │   └── rpi.png
│       └── js
│           ├── bootstrap.js
│           ├── bootstrap.min.js
│           └── npm.js
└── templates
    ├── index.html
    └── register.html
```

Comment: Did you type in the url manually or was it generated with `url_for`?

Comment: I typed it manually on the browser. I have made the webserver setup in my raspberry pi and trying to access the url in other devices on my home network.

Comment: Then generate a link in your index.html with `url_for("account_api.register")` and see if that one works.

Comment: what's the status? Did it work?

Comment: Thank you @Wombatz. its working for me. I also changed my configuration from Apache to nginx. Looks like I was missing something while making the setup. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Did the switching to nginx solve it or my suggestion? In the latter case i will write an answer so you can accept it.